How do I use Azure Functions Programming Model V1?
I just tried creating a new Azure Function, the way I've always done it, for the past 4-5 years...but this time, func init defaulted to the "V2 programming model". I don't want to use the completely different V2 programming model.
How do I create Azure Functions with the V1 programming model?

Cool. I was able to change the command found in this answer. The key is the V1 below.
Used func init <proj-name> --python -m V1
